# Reformulation of optimization problem using kkt and lagrange conditions

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Following setup:

$$ \begin{align}
\min_{y} &\frac{1}{2} y^T \bar{H} y \left(=V_k-V_{k+1}\right) \\
\text{s.t. } &x_{k+1}=Ax_k+Bu_k^*\\
             &U_k^* = \underset{U_k}{\arg \min} V_k,\\
             &U_{k+1}^* = \underset{U_{k+1}}{\arg \min} V_{k+1},
\end{align}$$
where I assume that $y = \begin{bmatrix}U_k^T, x_k^T, U_{k+1}^T,x_{k+1}^T\end{bmatrix}^T$, the Lyapunov function candidate
$$V_k = U_k^T H U_k + U_k^T G x_k + x_k^T \bar{Q}x_k$$
$\bar{H}$ is an indefinite matrix of appropriate dimension, $H$ is a positive semidefinite matrix of appropriate dimension ($H,G,\bar{Q}$ depend on $N$, not important here) and the two last equality constraints/min problems are convex, that is I can replace them with the sufficient and necessary KKT-conditions. I also assume that the two last min problems do not have any constraints. Lastly, $U_k = \begin{bmatrix}u_k^T, ...,u_{k+N-1}^T\end{bmatrix}^T$ with $x_k,u_k$ denoting the state and input of a discrete system at time $k$ and $N\in \mathbb{N}^+$ (for more detail, also regarding the other matrices, the problem is from [here](http://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1069607/FULLTEXT02.pdf).

If I replace the two last constraints with the (in this case lagrange) conditions, I can write the problem as
$$  \begin{align}
\min_{y} &\frac{1}{2} y^T \bar{H} y\\
\text{s.t. } &\bar{E}y=0,
\end{align}$$
where $\bar{E}$ collects
$$ \begin{align}
x_{k+1}=Ax_k+Bu_k,\\
HU_k + Gx_k = 0,\\
HU_{k+1}+Gx_{k+1}=0.
\end{align} $$
Now with $\bar{H}$ being indefinite, the kkt (in this case lagrange since no inequality constraints) conditions are only necessary if I wanted to replace the optimization problem. I end up with
$$\begin{align}
\bar{H}y + \bar{E}^T \lambda = 0\\
\bar{E} y =0\\
\end{align}$$
as neccessary conditions. This means that if there is a configuration such that $V_k-V_{k+1}$ is $<0$, I should be able to find it using those conditions.

Now by inspection, for a given $A,B,N$, I can find such a $y$. However, solving the system of conditions, I only find $y=0$ since if I reformulate to a homogenous matrix equation, the corresponding kernel of the matrix contains only the null vector. Furthermore I notice that in the optimum, $y$ satifies
$$  \bar{H} y = -\bar{E}^T\lambda$$
and thus
$$ \frac{1}{2} y^T \bar{H} y = -\frac{1}{2} y^T \bar{E}^T\lambda =-\frac{1}{2} \left(\bar{E} y\right) \lambda = 0.$$
Hence, I cannot ever get a solution from these conditions such that $\frac{1}{2} y^T \bar{H} y<0$?

**Question**

Obviously, something doesn't add up here. Is there a mistake in the derivation of those conditions?

Comment: Minimization of  a quadratic form subject to linear constraints (a subspace) gives either zero, if the quadratic form is non-negative on the subspace, or $-\infty$ otherwise. I guess already your reformulation might be wrong then if you need negative $y^T\bar Hy$ as an answer. However, $y^T\bar Hy=0$ does not mean necessarily $y=0$ if the matrix is not positive definite on the subspace.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The reformulation from $V_k-V_{k+1}$ to $y^T\bar{H}y$ is likely correct. As stated, I am able to find, for a specific $A,B,N$, a $y$ with $y^T\bar{H}y<0$. That is for the second optimization problem, I can find a $y$ which satisfies $y^T\bar{H}y<0$ under constraint $\bar{E}y=0$. As from there, I use neccesary but not sufficient conditions, shouldn't I, with what you said in mind, then get $-\infty$ instead of $0$? From my understanding, the final conditions should give me values of $y$ which contain the optimum, which should be $\leq$ the value i guessed.

Comment: Yes, then you get $-\infty$ and the necessary conditions (Lagrange or KKT) is not applicable. If $y_0^T\bar Hy_0<0$ with $\bar Ey_0=0$ then just set $y=ty_0$ and let $t\to\infty$ to see that the function is unbounded on the subspace ($\inf=-\infty$). You need more constraints on your control variable to make the problem reasonable (i.e. to ensure existence of min).

Comment: Can you elaborate on why I then cannot apply lagrange/KKT to the second optimization problem? Checking wikipedia for the KKT, it says that they are applicable as long as e.g. my constraints are affine functions, which they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example: take
$$
\bar H=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -2\end{bmatrix},\qquad \bar E=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then you are minimizing $y_1^2-2y_2^2$ subject to $y_1=y_2$.

The necessary condition gives
$$
\begin{cases}
y_1+\lambda&=&0,\\
-2y_2-\lambda&=&0
\end{cases}\quad\implies\quad y_1=2y_2.
$$
Together with $y_1=y_2$ it makes $y_1=y_2=0$, with the objective function being zero.

However, if you take a feasible point $y_1=y_2=1$ you get the smaller objective function value $-1<0$. What's wrong?

The wrong part is the application of the necessary condition, which is applicable **only if the minimum exists**. In our case, the minimum does not exist: take $y_1=y_2=t$ and let $t\to+\infty$, you get $-t^2\to-\infty$.

One can compare the phenomenon with an unconstrained minimization: $$\min x^3.$$ The necessary condition $3x^2=0$ gives the saddle point $x=0$ that has nothing to do with the solution (which does not exist).